# Pass mixed content with reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, web, cloud, reverse-proxy

I have a website and users create their own app. But i can't embed these apps on my website via iframe, because my website has SSL certificate and got this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://IP_ADDR'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

My workflow is like that:

- Click create button
- Deploy EC2 instance from AWS
- Get IP EC2 address from AWS
- Embed this app via iframe

I want to embed these IPs to my website, IP addresses are dynamic. Anyone can create machine anytime.

What is best practice solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice (and also the only I can think of) solution IMHO would be to use proper HTTPS for the iframe content also. You'd need a possibility to automatically create DNS records though (you can do so with AWS Route 53). Regarding SSL you could use a wildcard certificate (e.g. Let's Encrypt). Nginx could be configured to `proxy_pass` by DNS name as opposed to IP. Then your workflow would become this:

- Click create button
- Deploy EC2 instance from AWS
- Get IP EC2 address from AWS
- Create DNS record
- Embed this app via iframe

Comment: Thanks, looks valid but i have one question. This dns record could be take 48 hours for being valid.
I need embed quickly

Comment: New DNS records should be available instantly. Only if you change an *existing* record does it take some time until the updated record propagates.